# how to get right page number using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html

I cannot figure out which part is getting wrong in changing page No. I want to change to page no based on clicking,eg something like in forum. i need someone to help me. Is the code awkward and can suggest software to debug jQuery code.  Thanks!!

Check out this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/myhk2009/f2w1ko21/1/) to see it in action!

```
<div id="display" class="pager">
</div>
$(function () {
    totalPage = 10;
    pageStart = 1;
    skipPageFrom = pageStart + 1;
    skipPageTo = totalPage - 1;
    //initialize
    changePager(totalPage, pageStart, skipPageFrom, skipPageTo);

    //click to change pager
    $('.pager a').on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        //reset values
        pageStart = parseInt($(this).text());
        skipPageFrom = pageStart + 1;
        skipPageTo = totalPage - 1;
        changePager(totalPage, pageStart, skipPageFrom, skipPageTo);
    });

});
function changePager(totalPage, pageStart, skipPageFrom, skipPageTo) {
    $('#display').empty('');
    a_str = "";
    if ((totalPage - pageStart) > 5) {
        for (i = pageStart; i <= totalPage; i++) {
            if (i > skipPageFrom && i < skipPageTo) {
                a_str += "<span>...</span>";//add span to indicate skip pageNo
                i = skipPageTo - 1;         // skip values
            } else {
                a_str += "<a >" + i + "</a>";
            }
        }
    } else {
        pageStart = (totalPage - 4)<1 ? 1:(totalPage - 4) ;
        for (i = pageStart; i <= totalPage; i++) {
            a_str += "<a >" + i + "</a>";
        }
    }
    $('#display').append(a_str);
}
```

Comment: You will find any JavaScript errors (which include JQuery errors too) by right clic > inspect element > tab "Console", to see where are errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebug is great for debugging. You can download it in Firefox as an addon, it's my personal weapon of choice.

As for your problem, one item I can see is you need to defer your listener because you're creating the anchors dynamically (they don't exist when you fire the listener).

http://jsfiddle.net/f2w1ko21/3/

```
$('.pager').on('click', 'a', function (e) {
```

Comment: it works, but i donot quite understand, can u explain more? is code awkward?

Comment: When you're telling your program to look for a click event on the anchor element, the anchors at that point do not exist so it does not set it up. By changing it you set the listener to be on the parent element (`.pager`) and it will fire the function on any anchor's it finds within it.. Read [this article on jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events) for more info

Answer (score 1):

1. You create your buttons by calling `changePager()` (good)
2. You attach your click listeners (good)
3. On click, you call `changePager()` again... so you regenerate your buttons completely, so you destroy the clicks listeners on them. That's why it works only once.

If you work in Chrome, just hit F12 to show the debugger. In Firefox, download Firebug. If you're using internet explorer, you're screwed :)